# R: Finding the closest date (index) in a dataframe that comes after a specified date

Tags: r, date, dataframe, indexing

I'm currently trying to solve this problem in R:

Suppose I have given a randomly generated dataframe DF which look like this:

```
            Value
2009-10-21  46.14286
2009-12-22  46.33714
2010-02-23  46.42857
2010-04-27  46.12143
2010-06-28  46.55857
2010-08-29  46.60286
2010-10-30  46.49714
2010-12-31  46.13571
2011-06-03  46.52000
2011-08-04  47.49143
```

where the first column denotes the index of the data frame.
My goal is to write a function that deletes all entries before September 19th 2010. Normally, I would solve this problem something like this:

```
DF <- DF[c(-1:-6),]
```

However, in a randomly generated dataframe, I cannot know, which row has an index of after September 19th 2010, and which row has an index of before September 19th 2010.

Is there any function to find out the position of the first index that comes after September 19th 2010? (or any other approach to solve this problem)

Comment: You can check with the index .  i.e. `as.Date(row.names(DF)) > as.Date('2010-09-19') `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical index with the row.names of the dataset

```
i1 <- as.Date(row.names(DF)) >= as.Date('2010-09-19')
```

To find the position of the rows where it matches,

```
which(i1)
```

Use the index to subset the dataset

```
DF[i1, , drop = FALSE]
```